# Java: How do I start an imported file on a particular line?

Tags: java, file, loops

This is my loop which pulls from the in file. I can start one loop on line 0 (like this one does), but how would I start the loop from line 10, 20, 30, or 40 for this program or any program in general?

```
double sum = 0;
int j = 0;
while (j < 10) {
    if (in.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = in.nextLine();
        Double num = Double.parseDouble(line);
        sum += num;
        j++;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not enought lines");
    }
}
```

Comment: Use switch statement conditionals? Explain what you are doing.

Comment: There are 50 lines of numbers in my input.txt file. Each in order line1: 1, line2: 2, etc. Now I need to pull in the first ten for one person and average it. I only know how to pull in the first lines of code, I do not know how to start a new while statement and start the file at line 11.

Comment: I need to pull in the 11-20 lines and average them for the second person

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would put another Loop before the actual reading loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<startline; i++){ 
    if(!in.hasNextLine()){ 
        break; 
    }
    in.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks I took your advise on this one. My for(int i=0; i < 49; i++) did not work correctly so what I did was remove the i++ in the for loop and put it at the end of each while loop. I had 5 while loops, while(i<10),while(i<20), etc. This continued until 49. A big part of my error was brackets (}). I thought it would not work if I closed each While statement inside a bracket, but because of the outside counter you showed, it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

this code should read the lines and put in a list (named sums) the sum of every 10 rows

```
    int j=0;
    int sum=0;
    List<Integer> sums=new ArrayList<>();
    while(in.hasNextLine()) {
        j++;
        String line = in.nextLine();
        Double num = Double.parseDouble(line);
        sum += num;
        if ((j % 10)==0) {
            sums.add(sum);
            sum=0;
        }           

    }
    if ((j % 10)!=0) {
        System.out.println("Not enought lines");
    }
```